# Google API PHP consent screen - only one time

Tags: google-api-php-client

I was following the sample below and notice that every time it shows the consent screen to the user. Is there a way to show the consent screen only the first time?

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/userinfo/index.php

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you still need this , just add this line to your code.

```
$client->setApprovalPrompt ("auto");
```

The consent screen will prompt for the first time only or when the token is revoked from account.